# How to set central widget fill in the whole main window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, borderless

I have a minimal example like this:

```
mWidget = new QWidget;
vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
mLabel = new QLabel;
mLabel->setText("Text");
mLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
mLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel { border: 2px solid red; }");
this->setCentralWidget(mWidget);
mWidget->setLayout(vLayout);
vLayout->addWidget(mLabel);
```

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, apart from the `central widget`, there are still some white border outside the red border. What I am trying to do is to let the central widget fill in the whole main window, so there will be no white border outside the red border. Maybe in another way to say is to make a borderless window(do not know if a borderless window is what I am looking for). I googled how to make a borderless window, and I tried `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`, but it is not what I want. I am pretty confused about how to achieve this now? So is the topic `How to make a borderless window` what I should look into? If it is, does that mean I should invoke some windows api to make that work? Or I should just do it with some other Qt methods? 
Hope someone can provide me a way or give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to set the layout margins to 0 with `vLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` ?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Just tried that, that is what I am looking for. Did not except that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use the `QMainWindow`? It seems that people use that class without thinking what it is for. You **only ever** want to use `QMainWindow` if you have toolbars, status bar, or docking sub-windows. Otherwise it's pointless. What you want is the "central widget" be the only widget, without being embedded in the main window. If you've designed it in a `.ui` file, you'll have to edit it manually to change the class to `QWidget`, and remove the intervening and now redundant `centralWidget` completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the designer in the current version of Qt Creator (8.0+) you can right click on MainWindow and select "Remove Status Bar". This will allow your centralwidget to fill the MainWindow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your Question  QMainwindow frame geometry and QLable geometry should be adjusted.so you can use like this below lines code.

```
setGeometry(0,0,320,280);
ui->label->setGeometry(0,0,320,245);
```